# PyQt How to set header labels with QTreeView

Tags: python, pyqt

While customizing `QTreeView` widget where each item is composed of different widget (`combo box`, `line edit` and etc) aligned in a row I came across a problem of not being able to customize the header labels (the names for the columns). With `QTreeWidget()` it was `setHeaderLabels([])`...

```
import sys, os
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

class TreeWidgetsItems(QtGui.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TreeWidgetsItems, self).__init__()

        self.itemModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 2)
        self.setModel(self.itemModel)

        item0 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item 0')
        self.itemModel.setItem(0, 0, item0)
        item0.setCheckable(True)

        item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item 1')
        self.itemModel.setItem(0, 1, item1)

        item2 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item 2')
        self.itemModel.setItem(0, 2, item2)

        item3 = QtGui.QStandardItem('Item 3')
        self.itemModel.setItem(0, 3, item3)

        lineedit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        itemIndex1 = self.itemModel.index(0, 1, QtCore.QModelIndex())
        self.setIndexWidget(itemIndex1, lineedit1)

        self.combo2 = QtGui.QComboBox() 
        itemIndex2 = self.itemModel.index(0, 2, QtCore.QModelIndex())
        self.setIndexWidget(itemIndex2, self.combo2)
        for i in range(5):
            self.combo2.addItem('Item'+str(i))

        self.dateEdit = QtGui.QDateEdit()
        self.dateEdit.setDateTime(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime())
        self.dateEdit.setMaximumDate(QtCore.QDate(7999, 12, 28))
        self.dateEdit.setMaximumTime(QtCore.QTime(23, 59, 59))
        self.dateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)

        itemIndex3 = self.itemModel.index(0, 3, QtCore.QModelIndex())
        self.setIndexWidget(itemIndex3, self.dateEdit)

        self.setColumnWidth(0, 60)
        for i in range(1, 7):
            self.setColumnWidth(i, 200)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TreeWidgetsItems()
    window.resize(960, 240)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Something like this?

    self.itemModel.setHorizontalItem(0, QtGui.QStandardItem('Column1'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `for i in range(1, 7):` loop to this:

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    self.setColumnWidth(i, 200)
    self.itemModel.setHeaderData(i, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Column {}'.format(i))
self.itemModel.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Column {}'.format("0"))
```

That last line is supposed to be outside of your for loop. It is setting your 0-indexed column title. The others will be set as you iterate from 1 to 7 in your loop.

The output looks like this:

[image: Headers are set]

---